# Does WinRar leave cache of opened Zip Archives (Nothing extracted)

Tags: data-leakage, windows-10, software, zip

Downloaded a .zip, via a secure app that deleted the only place it was downloaded (supposedly, who knows if defragmentation left other traces, the download happened by accident, on main OS WIN10, no containers or sandbox). Would the fact that I opened/previewed the archive leave recoverable files/folders/fullarchive somewhere?

[Similar Question, but doesn't seem to address if nothing was extracted.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57748/does-winrar-leave-traces-of-temporarily-extracted-files?rq=1)

I think this question needs clarification in case nothing was extracted.

Comment: The archive file name would be logged. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The file name wouldn't actually mind as much as the actual file (and containing files, since we're talking about an archive)

Comment: You could start to answer this by using Process Monitor (from Sysinternals) and running WinRar. The output will show if any files are written using standard APIs.